# Bookmark/Tag using 'I like it' and 'Tags & Notes' features

Tags: 2010, social, tagging

I'm trying to implement a "Bookmark" functionality on my article pagelayouts in SharePoint 2010.

I noticed that *I like it* and *Tags & Notes* are farm featueres, so they are visible on all the sites. I'm trying to use as much OOTB SharePoint as possible, so I was wondering if it is possible to insert them as SharePoint webcontrols or are they bound to a specific PlaceHolder in the masterpage?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know "I Like it" and "Tags & Notes" is coming from a FEATURE called SocialRibbonControl

More information here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721062.aspx

You can check what commands are executed by looking at: SocialRibbonControl\SocialRibbonControl.xml file. The commands referred in this xml file are mostly in SP.UI.SocialRibbon.JS file in SharePointRoot\Layouts folder.

There are no web controls that I am aware of which you can directly place in your pages .

Comment: I've found out there is a delegate control which you can insert in the masterpage containing this functionality. I just now need to figure out how to manipulate it a bit. Thank you for your reply! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

tried making bookmarks or anchor links?

select the section you wish to be the destination for the master link. In edit mode select insert- click Link dropdown box- click from address- and insert the URL of site and in the bottom bar write the what you wish the link to be known by (a number:1,2,3 or bookmark 1 bookmark 2 etc) click save and close. Then in edit mode you select the master link at top (the area that if you click it will take you to the anchor or bookmark we just created) and click insert -link dropdown- from address- and in the address column you enter '#' followed by the name of the link we created if you. If you called it  '1' or 'bookmark1'the you will enter '#1' or '#bookmark1' respectively. click Save and close and test the link.

My problem is, I need to know if theres a limit to the amount of links one can create?

Comment: Hi welcome to the wonderful SharePoint community. You are more than welcome to participate in asking questions and posting answers. But I am afraid that your current answer is not actually providing an answer. You can consider to ask your own question.